# Should I accept bounced emails when the emails are automatically generated from a "no-reply" user?

Tags: email, bounce

I have a website that generates emails based on user action such as registration on the site. These emails have a "no-reply" user name as I do not intend to receive a reply from them. Should I accept bounced emails in case some of these mails failed to deliver? (I understand that I can use a different envelope sender for such purpose.)

Currently, my server drops all incoming packets from port 25. I wonder if there is any negative impact on my email domain if these mails couldn't bounce back to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security and email delivery, I recommend you always handle bounces.

**Security**

If your form is spammed or compromised, receiving bounces is a good way to quickly detect this.  I investigate spam related incidents nearly every week for people who have compromised web applications.  If the bounces go to an account that you monitor, you can quickly spot an update in bounced emails and spot the issue.

**Email Delivery**

Users make typos and email will bounce.  You've not mentioned what you doing with the form, but if you are collecting emails for future use, then you will want to purge your email list of any bounced emails.

I've seen many lead generation systems that do not properly handle email bounces. As a result, you pollute your list with invalid emails.  When you then email this list,  your get bounces again.  This lowers your server's sending reputation and can negatively impact email delivery.

**Business Benefit**

There's also a business benefit.

I do IT support work and people contact us using a form on our site.

Some people contact us about email server issues using an email address that goes to the problematic server.

We used to get calls saying they contacted us but we never responded.  Since we monitor bounces, we can call them and follow up.

Comment: Thank you for the clear guidelines. For my particular case, I am CAPTCHA to counter SPAM registration. Only registered users whose email address has been verified would received further emails from me. I am using webform as the official communication channel and yes, I think it would be prudent to track bounces, but I would have to evaluate the trade-off for having another administrative overhead.